# Integration into android's settings

Tags: java, android

I want to add new item to the android settings, i.e. go to menu -> settings-> "my item". Is it possible? Second task is to add some menu items to an existing settings item, i.e.  go to menu -> settings-> Wireless & Networks, press on the VPN settings some time and see a menu with "my item". What must i do to done these tasks?

UPD: Can I change standard settings app, i.e. I will have created a new custom setting app, and when my app (not settings app) will be installed I'll remove standard settings app, and install my settings app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

You can create settings via `Settings` helper class that look the same as system settings, but they will be part of your app, not part of system settings menus.

Comment: what about if we download the source code of android and then modify it? then its worked or not?

Comment: Maybe on rooted phones. But not on normal phones - apps do not have system access due to security restrictions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes, I know it, But if I want to modify the android os for my personal device then I can modify the setting of the android device. right?

Comment: Custom ROMs often have custom setting menus. For example Cyanogen Mod.