# How can i integrate a app into the phone settings?

Tags: android, xml

Nova Launcher has an integration with cm9 settings like settings-->launcher

now i want to access an application through settings & i don't want any icon in app drawer..is this possible..can someone point me to a tutorial or an example..

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible. Because System Settings itself is an app and you cannot push-in your contents into another app unless there's any interface available for this, which in this case Not.

The reason why cm9 has it because its a custom ROM and the developers have customly tailored its setting's section to integrate options from its supported packages at one place.

Comment: i didn't mean like to load the entire app into settings but to create access through settings to the app,

Comment: Yes, I can understand what you mean, but still its not possible to make your app's settings available in System Settings.

Comment: hmmm..i guess ill have to dig deeper than i thought,anyway thanks for the quick reply's mate

Comment: if you are interested, you can take a port of CM9 for your device, modify its System Settings class to include settings from your app, rebuild it and package it together with your app and finally install to your device. But then i guess its already too much fuzz :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with a stock ROM, as you say Nova Launcher does it on Cyanogen.
Similar question: [Integration into android's settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444156/integration-into-androids-settings)

Comment: am on CM9 so i have root privileges..is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: I've found this link: http://review.cyanogenmod.com/#/c/15818/ cm adds an intent to display launcher settings so, if your app is a launcher you can use it, otherwise you're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about CM9-specific APIs (which may or may not exist).

In stock Android, your app can appear under Settings > Accounts & sync if you implement [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). You will need to create a mock account if your app does not require sign in. I remember HTC Sense doing this with some of their apps (e.g. weather) at some point, not sure about the most recent versions though.

Comment: i guess i have to rip novalauncher.apk to find the answer :)

Comment: @AntoDanny did you find anything that can be shared??